# How to use GREP and put the results on diferent columns but on the same lines

Tags: sed, grep

Right here I have an example of an input that I want to use to generate a specific output.

```
  1.2840   -1.6830    1.4460 C 
  1.5660   -0.8240    0.2163 C 
  0.5584    0.2995   -0.0595 C 
 -0.8805   -0.1514   -0.2412 C 
 -1.6205   -0.3785    0.8741 O 
 -1.4770    0.3883    2.0816 C 
 -1.3875   -0.2971   -1.3503 O 
 -2.0561    1.7788    1.8987 C 
  1.8097   -1.5560   -0.8246 O 
  2.8979   -0.2777    0.3226 N 
  1.2555   -1.0711    2.3543 H 
  0.3266   -2.2122    1.3666 H 
  2.0525   -2.4514    1.6103 H 
  0.8193    0.8445   -0.9811 H 
  0.6122    1.0718    0.7144 H 
 -0.4400    0.4244    2.4204 H 
 -2.0425   -0.1400    2.8563 H 
 -3.0985    1.7209    1.5688 H 
 -1.5098    2.3359    1.1312 H 
 -2.0131    2.3425    2.8349 H 
  3.1017    0.3084    1.1257 H 
  3.4860   -1.1139    0.2817 H 
  3.0712    0.1760   -0.5761 H
```

The last column corresponds to atoms of a molecule and the other columns are the coordinates of these atoms.

In the original file I have a lot of lines like on this example and a lot of other things, using some codes I could (with grep) catch these lines and isolate than in one unique file. 
But, the problem is that the column corresponding to the atoms is to the right of the coordinates, and I need it to be to the left of the coordinates in my output. Is there any way to do this?

I was thinking of grep because I'm using it to extract the coordinates and atoms from my original file, but it is not working until now.

Below is what I need, exactly:

```
C   1.2840   -1.6830    1.4460
C   1.5660   -0.8240    0.2163
C   0.5584    0.2995   -0.0595
C  -0.8805   -0.1514   -0.2412
O  -1.6205   -0.3785    0.8741
C  -1.4770    0.3883    2.0816
O  -1.3875   -0.2971   -1.3503
C  -2.0561    1.7788    1.8987
O   1.8097   -1.5560   -0.8246
N   2.8979   -0.2777    0.3226
H   1.2555   -1.0711    2.3543
H   0.3266   -2.2122    1.3666
H   2.0525   -2.4514    1.6103
H   0.8193    0.8445   -0.9811
H   0.6122    1.0718    0.7144
H  -0.4400    0.4244    2.4204
H  -2.0425   -0.1400    2.8563
H  -3.0985    1.7209    1.5688
H  -1.5098    2.3359    1.1312
H  -2.0131    2.3425    2.8349
H   3.1017    0.3084    1.1257
H   3.4860   -1.1139    0.2817
H   3.0712    0.1760   -0.5761
```

Comment: Can you show a small example of the output you want?

Comment: Use `awk` for this. You can test a specific column, and reorder the columns in the results.

Comment: `grep` is for printing only the lines that match a pattern But it looks like your result has all the same lines as the input, why do you think `grep` is the right thing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed you can get last character and put it first

```
sed "s/^\(.*\)\(.\)$/\2\1/g" /tmp/atom.txt
```

```
C  1.2840   -1.6830    1.4460 
C  1.5660   -0.8240    0.2163 
C  0.5584    0.2995   -0.0595 
C -0.8805   -0.1514   -0.2412 
O -1.6205   -0.3785    0.8741 
C -1.4770    0.3883    2.0816 
O -1.3875   -0.2971   -1.3503 
C -2.0561    1.7788    1.8987 
O  1.8097   -1.5560   -0.8246 
N  2.8979   -0.2777    0.3226 
H  1.2555   -1.0711    2.3543 
H  0.3266   -2.2122    1.3666 
H  2.0525   -2.4514    1.6103 
H  0.8193    0.8445   -0.9811 
H  0.6122    1.0718    0.7144 
H -0.4400    0.4244    2.4204 
H -2.0425   -0.1400    2.8563 
H -3.0985    1.7209    1.5688 
H -1.5098    2.3359    1.1312 
H -2.0131    2.3425    2.8349 
H  3.1017    0.3084    1.1257 
H  3.4860   -1.1139    0.2817 
H  3.0712    0.1760   -0.5761
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{print $4 " " $1 " " $2 " " $3 }' /tmp/atom.txt
```

Will give you

```
C 1.2840 -1.6830 1.4460
C 1.5660 -0.8240 0.2163
C 0.5584 0.2995 -0.0595
C -0.8805 -0.1514 -0.2412
O -1.6205 -0.3785 0.8741
C -1.4770 0.3883 2.0816
O -1.3875 -0.2971 -1.3503
C -2.0561 1.7788 1.8987
O 1.8097 -1.5560 -0.8246
N 2.8979 -0.2777 0.3226
H 1.2555 -1.0711 2.3543
H 0.3266 -2.2122 1.3666
H 2.0525 -2.4514 1.6103
H 0.8193 0.8445 -0.9811
H 0.6122 1.0718 0.7144
H -0.4400 0.4244 2.4204
H -2.0425 -0.1400 2.8563
H -3.0985 1.7209 1.5688
H -1.5098 2.3359 1.1312
H -2.0131 2.3425 2.8349
H 3.1017 0.3084 1.1257
H 3.4860 -1.1139 0.2817
H 3.0712 0.1760 -0.5761
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` with `printf` to get the aligned columns:

```
awk '{ printf "%s %8s %9s %9s\n", $4, $1, $2, $3}' test.txt
```

which gives:

```
C   1.2840   -1.6830    1.4460
C   1.5660   -0.8240    0.2163
C   0.5584    0.2995   -0.0595
C  -0.8805   -0.1514   -0.2412
O  -1.6205   -0.3785    0.8741
C  -1.4770    0.3883    2.0816
O  -1.3875   -0.2971   -1.3503
C  -2.0561    1.7788    1.8987
O   1.8097   -1.5560   -0.8246
N   2.8979   -0.2777    0.3226
H   1.2555   -1.0711    2.3543
H   0.3266   -2.2122    1.3666
H   2.0525   -2.4514    1.6103
H   0.8193    0.8445   -0.9811
H   0.6122    1.0718    0.7144
H  -0.4400    0.4244    2.4204
H  -2.0425   -0.1400    2.8563
H  -3.0985    1.7209    1.5688
H  -1.5098    2.3359    1.1312
H  -2.0131    2.3425    2.8349
H   3.1017    0.3084    1.1257
H   3.4860   -1.1139    0.2817
H   3.0712    0.1760   -0.5761
```